# Dynamic form element names in Blade for Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, arrays, forms, laravel-blade, laravel-5

I'm attempting to create a form to update multiple rows of data from a table.  The table has four columns ( cola, colb, colc, cold ).  I am generating the form dynamically with a foreach loop in my view.  At present I am using

```
text('cola[][cola]', $this->cola...
```

And on down to name and then populate the form fields.  This works fine except that it returns an array of four arrays ( cola, colb, colc, cold ), so that I have all of my cola values in one array and all of my colb values in another etc.

What I would like is to return an array of each row that is submitted, so that my result would be something like

```
0(cola=3, colb=7, colc=2, cold=99)
```

So that I can access the values simply with a for each loop.  I am, however, HTML remedial and cannot seem to get the name right on the form elements to accomplish this.  I know that the answer is obvious, but I keep running into either the arrays I do not want or only submitting the data from the final row.

Edit for clarifications...

Use of

```
text('row[$this->key][cola]'
```

Or

```
text('row[$i][cola]'
```

with $i as an iterator results in one array with the name of $i or $this->key that only returns the last row submitted. Removing the quotes, as in

```
text(row[$i][cola]
```

Results in an undefined constant, because the string is expected.

The closest that I have come to success is

```
text('row['<php echo $i ?>'][cola]'
```

This actually names the form elements correctly, but breaks the elements themselves.  They render as plain text and not as input boxes.  I really am going a bit bonkers on this one.

Comment: Start with rows then cols? i.e. `text('row[][cola]', $this->cola...`

Comment: That only submits the last row of the form.

Comment: Not if you have the array brackets as part of the row name. It would return all of them since it is an array.

Comment: Using the row brackets as part of the name, as in {text('row[][cola]'...} results in each element being assigned it's own array.  So that if I have 10 rows I return 40 separate arrays.

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. Sorry, my quick code wasn't clear. You need a counter in the $row.  `text('row[$incrementer][cola]'` If you are in a for loop use the incrementer from that. Otherwise add a new $i++ to your foreach loop. So after your fourth col, you would increase $i by one, for the next row.

Comment: And that's where I keep running into problems.  I'm using a counter, but I can't figure out how to place it inside the brackets for row.  The name is a string literal and when I try to use 'row[$i]' or 'row[{{ $i }}]' both are just treated as part of the string and it becomes one array that contains only the values of the last field.

Answer (score 0):

`''` is for string literals, you want interpolation, `""`.

```
$a = 'hi';
echo "$a there";
// hi there
```